# context.select isn't defined for BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

Why I can't use any extension methods of Provider (`context.select`, `context.read` and `context.listen`)?

I get a static error like this.

> The method 'select' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.Try
> correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
> method named 'select'..

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Following line causes the problem
    var isFavorite = context.select<FavModel, bool>(
      (fav) => fav.items.contains(item),
    );

    return OtherWidget(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should import provider package in this file.

Comment: Yes the screenshot is a part of the code which I have posted and the package is imported

Comment: What is your provider version?

Comment: It is `provider: ^3.0.0`

Comment: You should [upgrade](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/changelog#410).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`context.select`, `context.read` and `context.listen` are [extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods#:%7E:text=Extension%20methods%2C%20introduced%20in%20Dart,extension%20methods%20alongside%20regular%20methods.) from Provider. To use them you should import Provider.

Add this on top of your file:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```

It should be auto-imported by default. It's a known [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38894).

Comment: in my case it should be import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart'; Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 7):

I was Using Bloc in VS Code and while call context.read I got this error. This error is because I haven't imported the bloc library. that's why I got this type of error. Make sure you have imported a relevant library. in My Case

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi if using riverpod and get error for `contect.read`
add this line

```
 import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
```

Comment: hi man, still getting same error even though importing the flutter_riverpod file, kindly help

Comment: Hi, contect.read has deprecated in last version of riverpod, please follow documentations.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for guiding, now it is ref.read and we need to convert StatelessWidget to ConsumerWidget